# Flutter - How to get the build number of the app?

Tags: flutter, dart, versioning, semantic-versioning

I understand the usage of package_info_plus package and I am able to get the version number correctly.

The issue here is that the Build number of our application is decided by Github Runner on release as follows:

```
--build-number=${{github.run_number}}
```

I want to display this number in-app. Is it possible?

```
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: PackageInfo.fromPlatform(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                design.BodyText(context.localized.appVersion),
                design.BodyText(
                  "${snapshot.data!.version}(${snapshot.data!.buildNumber})",
                ),
              ],
            );
          }
          return const SizedBox();
        })
```

The build number here is from pubspec.yaml. I would want the Github runner based build number to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Github Actions to build and deploy your app, you could edit your yml file to put the build number in your env variables.
For example :

```
name: PRODUCTION

env:
  APP_VERSION: ${{github.ref_name}}
  APP_BUILD_NUM : ${{github.run_number}}

on:
  push:
     ...
```

And then from your flutter app, you could get it with :

```
String appBuildNum =
const String.fromEnvironment('APP_BUILD_NUM', defaultValue: '123');
```

Comment: Ohhh this is interesting! Will try this out. In debug mode, it should show up as 123 I'm assuming?

Comment: Assuming you're setting env variables only on production, it will default to 123 on dev mode, yes.